# How to invoke method of MarshalByRefObject-derived object without assembly defining the object?

Tags: .net, clr, remoting

I need to call a method on an object loaded into another appdomain.
I can't load assembly with this type definition, nor assembly with any of it's base types. (once loaded, these assemblies can't be unloaded, what is not acceptable for my task)
Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Use interfaces](http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/net-remoting-faq/useinterfaceswithconfigfiles).

Alternatively, use a newer technology such as WCF.

> Read the question first...

I did read it.  If I've misunderstood it, maybe you could clarify what I've missed.

If you use interfaces, you will of course need to load the assembly containing the interface Type, but you won't need to load the assembly containing the implementation.  This is as good as you can get; you need to load *something* that describes what needs to be marshaled.